# (YouTube API): YT.Player doesnt work playVideo

Tags: youtube, yt

I need to develop autoplay when user visit the page, actually apply code snippet as provided in google doc:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and it doesn't work properly, video doesn't play/
I've tried to put `event.target.playVideo();` in setTimeout with delay 1000, 2000, 3000, but this experiment is failed as well - video didn't play
Could you help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your problem is the autoplay policy most browsers implement.
It prevents autoplay in most cases.

One exception is that autoplay works when the video sound is muted. Maybe that is something that works for your use case.

For further reference visit:

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay

https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

Comment: I think what you describe is due to those exceptions from the blockage of autoplay by the browser. Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
The user has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.) or
on desktop if the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.

Comment: Yep, you're right. It works as expected for Safary, definitely, it's browser policy. Do you know probably some arounds which may help in this case?

Comment: No, i don't sorry. I guess it will be pretty hard to bypass that, since it is hardcoded into the browser and bypassing it would basically mean to overwrite the users own configuration. You could run the video without sound and do something to get the user to interact with the website and enable the sound on the running video afterwards. After that if the user switches the page you can just let it autoplay even with sound, since the interaction has been done before.